# Writing a name after a dash

Tags: dashes, em-dashes

In my thesis, I want to thank my friend "XY". So I was wondering if it is correct to write the following:

*Lastly, I want to express my most profound appreciation to the person who was there for me emotionally and mentally while supporting me from the day we met - XY.*

Now I want to know if it is correct to write her name after the dash in this sentence? Or if writing creates any ambiguities.

Comment: Please do use a dash and not a hyphen, though.

Comment: Sometimes you see at the end of a statement something like "—XY", meaning that the statement is signed by XY.  In fact, look after this comment to see such an example

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct, it refers to the "person who was there for [you]" clause. There are no ambiguities here.

Answer (score -1):

Formally, you would want to thank

> ... the person who was there for me and supported me: XY.

or

> ... the person who was there for me and supported me, XY.

A dash following an epigram should be an em dash, and normally precedes an *attribution*.  For example,

> XY, you were always there for me and supported me. Never say never again. — Bond007

Em dashes may be used internally, so there could be some ambiguity.  For example,

. ... to the person—XY—who was always there for me and supported me.

I wouldn’t write this sentence with a final phrase set off by an em dash, however.  That is more the function of a colon or comma.

Comment: In the question, the name comes before the period. It is not a dash following an epigram, but a dash as part of an epigram.

Comment: I think this answer shows that there is some ambiguity. My first instinct was also to see the dash as part of an attribution.